# Is it possible to find out if an Apache module is loaded in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I'm looking at finding a way of checking if an apache module is loaded within a PHP script. The module in question is `mod_xsendfile` so that I can determine if I can use the `X-SENDFILE` header to output a secure file to the browser if available, or if I need to use readfile(). Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+get+apache+modules). [First result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php)!

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thanks Dave, I really did do research into this, but I'm guessing since I wouldn't have put the word "get" in the search, its not likely to come up. I did use this query `programatically check if apache module is loaded using php` but as you can see from the results, it didnt match

Comment: `apache_get_modules()` is the third result if you just search "php apache modules". Less is more with Google searching, the skill is being able to select the important keywords about what you are looking for. **EDIT** *this is true for google.co.uk (my default) but oddly not for google.com*

Comment: It was actually on the third page when I searched just now...

Comment: I know see edit in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you find out that `mod_xsendfile` is loaded from within PHP, you need to keep in mind that this says nothing about it's configuration. You can not just automagically use it, because if available, it requires specific configuration to work with your PHP script.

Apart from that, there is [`apache_get_modules`](http://php.net/apache_get_modules) if you use PHP as an apache module itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- [`apache_get_modules` — Get a list of loaded Apache modules](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php)

Example from Manual:

```
print_r(apache_get_modules());
```

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => core
    [1] => http_core
    [2] => mod_so
    [3] => sapi_apache2
    [4] => mod_mime
    [5] => mod_rewrite
)
```